# Configurando Rotas AngulasJS com ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net, rotas

Estou com problema ao realizar roteamento angularJS com asp.net mvc.

Configurei meu roteamento no app.js e quando clico nos meus links as páginas não estão sendo redirecionadas corretamente, única página que aparece corretamente é a Home.html, mas depois que eu clico nos links as mesmas não funcionam, muda a URL mas fica sempre cm o Home.html.

> Minha Index Principal

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="../AngularJS/app/app.js"></script>

    <script src="../AngularJS/controller/homeController.js"></script>
    <script src="../AngularJS/controller/autorController.js"></script>
    <script src="../AngularJS/controller/editoraController.js"></script>
    <script src="../AngularJS/controller/livroController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

    <a ng-href="#/Home"> Home </a> |
    <a ng-href="#/Autor"> Listar Autores </a> |
    <a ng-href="#/Editora"> Listar Editoras </a> |
    <a ng-href="#/Livro"> Listar Livros </a>

    <div ng-view="">
        
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

> Configurando o app Angular JS

```js
(function () {
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", { controller: "homeController", templateUrl: "/AngularJS/view/Home/Home.html" })
        .when("/Livro", { controller: "livroController", templateUrl: "/AngularJS/view/Livro/Livro.html" })
        .when("/Autor", { controller: "autorController", templateUrl: "/AngularJS/view/Autor/Autor.html" })
        .when("/Editora", { controller: "editoraController", templateUrl: "/AngularJS/view/Editora/Editora.html" })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

});
}());
```

> Controller Home AngularJS

```js
(function () {
    angular.module("app").controller("homeController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.home = " Home ";
    });
}());
```

> Controller Livro Ahgular JS

```js
(function () {
    angular.module("app").controller("livroController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.livro = "Primeiro Livro";
    });
}());
```

> HtmlPage  Home

```html
<div ng-controller="homeController">

    Pagina Inicial - {{home}}

</div>
```

> Html Page Livro

```html
<div ng-controller="livroController">  
    Livro Index - {{livro}}
 </div>
```

> Página inicial aberta corretamente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Ao clicar no Link Livro - Muda a url mas não abre a página Livro.html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Estrutura dos arquivos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que a pasta Views por padrão é especial, o `Web.config` localizado dentro dela modifica o comportamento de requisições para arquivos dentro dela e por isso ele retorna que não encontrou o arquivo.

Se você não vai utilizar de forma alguma os Controllers e Views do ASP.Net MVC você pode excluir o `Web.config` que está dentro desta pasta e ela vai funcionar como uma pasta qualquer, e neste caso eu diria para remover o `_ViewStart.cshtml` e pasta `Shared` também, ou a outra alternativa é usar uma pasta com um nome diferente para os seus templates do AngularJS.

Comment: Leandro, deu certo par carregar minha view home, fiz exatamente o que me pediu, só que só tem um porém, as rotas para as outras páginas não estão funcionando, conseguiria me ajudar ? vou atutalizar meus fontes

Comment: Arrumei a estrutura dos meus arquivos, e também meu app.js

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver este meu problema da seguinte forma!

Ao invés

```
de : <a ng-href="#/Home"> Home </a>
coloquei: <a ng-href="#!/Home"> Home </a>

<body ng-app="app">

    <a ng-href="#!/Home"> Home </a> |
    <a ng-href="#!/Autor"> Listar Autores </a> |
    <a ng-href="#!/Editora"> Listar Editoras </a> |
    <a ng-href="#!/Livro"> Listar Livros </a>

    <div ng-view="">

    </div>

</body>
```